# Change register success template

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-account, confirmation

After customer confirms their account via mail by this style of link:

```
site.dev/customer/account/confirm/?id=47&key=2dc2e5b29dda81cf4c1e174bd67b85c5
```

They are redirected to `site.dev/customer/account/index/` which displays the dashboard and the message, that confirm is good.

I want to show different template for message after confirm mail.

I tired to make some changes in `AccountController`, but this has not helped.

Transaction mail in CMS not working!

Maybe somebody do something similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `confirmAction()` method in `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php`. It redirects to `site.dev/customer/account/index/`. You should remove `$this->_redirectSuccess($this->_getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true)));` and handle that like you want.